# SQLAlchemy and PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

With `cx_Oracle`, [we can easily call PL/SQL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/prez-stored-proc-084100.html) procedures using the following:

```
import cx_Oracle
db = cx_Oracle.Connection("hr/hrpwd@//localhost:1521/XE")
cursor = db.cursor()

l_department_id = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER) # This is an OUT param
cursor.callproc("PKG_HR.ADD_DEPARTMENT",
  [l_department_id, p_department_name, p_manager_id, p_location_id]

l_department_id = 5
l_count = self.__cursor.callfunc("PKG_HR.GET_EMPLOYEE_COUNT",
  cx_Oracle.NUMBER, [p_department_id])
```

How can we handle PL/SQL through SQLAlchemy? There is not much on Google, and I'm using the following approach which I find rather awkward:

```
from sqlalchemy import bindparam, outparam, Numeric

proc = text('BEGIN do_something(:id_in, :count_out); END', bindparams=[
    bindparam('id_in', 12345, Numeric), outparam('count_out', Numeric)
])

result = connection.execute(proc)

print result.out_parameters['row_count']
```

Another thread on Stackoverflow mentioned that we could use this approach instead, but the out parameters do not work:

```
result = connection.execute('BEGIN do_something(:id_in); END;',
                   {'id_in': 12345 });

# assert result.out_parameters is None
```

So, is there a much cleaner way of executing PL/SQL in SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Your link about calling PL/SQL procedures with cx_Oracle points to an article on the Onion -- I doubt you intended that! And if it is easy to do with cx_Oracle why not use it for that purpose? Why do you want to use SQLAlchemy for that purpose? Is it just to avoid using more than one library as much as possible?

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga Thanks; edited. I'm already using SQLAlchemy; there is just a new requirement to call a PL/SQL proc, and it feels a bit clunky.